# Login redirect loop after upgrading website from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-5.0

I have just updated to `net5.0` from `netcoreapp3.1`. So far that has only meant changing a bunch of project file XML.

When I run my website locally and hit the homepage `/` I am sent into a redirect loop on my login route.

A quick Google shows no immediate gotchas when doing this upgrade. I'm leaving this question here so I can potentially answer it myself when I've resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

**Cleaning the solution and rebuilding sorted it.**

For complete disclosure:

I also moved `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(...)` call to after calling `services.AddIdentityCore<...>(...)` but tested it and that didn't seem to solve it.

And I remmed out the `[Authorize]` on the controller that handles my login route, though I subsequently unremmed it and it continues to work.

Note that I deleted all `bin` and `obj` folders as part of the upgrade process as per the official upgrade doc, but a final clean was obviously needed.